# Ubuntu 22.04 taking way too much disk space

Tags: disk-usage

Recently I installed Ubuntu on my 120GB SSD card. I only installed basic software and tools. But my disk space keeps decreasing day by day and I don't have any files or applications that takes that much space. can anyone help me fix this issue and save some space?

Comment: Take a look at your log-files in /var/log. Some of them might be growing.

Comment: How much disk space decreases every day?

Answer (score 1):

There can be a couple of things which can be done.

1. Good old way is to find the files which are taking space:

Run from root user in / directory

```
du -sh *
```

This will give the sizes of files and directories. Keep digging in by going inside the directory with big size and running it again, until you find the files which are causing issue.

2. Use disk usage analyser. It is a GUI tool which will help you in finding the files which are taking more space.
3. Check common paths like /var/log, /var/tmp and see if any large unnecessary files are present.

Answer (score 0):

Search for how to clean Ubuntu 22.04 safely if your version is different put that version. two interesting sites I found were https://www.geeksmint.com/keep-ubuntu-system-clean/ and https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/clean-ubuntu.html. I wouldn't use cleaning thumbnails, because that one uses rm -rf and there are some thumbnails that belong to Ubuntu, if you decide to do it make sure that you know everything about that cache.  In regard to Remove most Asian fonts or Set a reasonable maximum log size for systemd I have not done them and don't know if they messes up your Ubuntu.
Remove Old Kernels, the lines that started with rc mean that they are only configured, they are not using any disk space, but if you want to even remove those you can run sudo apt purge packagename and do not remove any thing else in my case it shows 2 signed + 1 generic.
For cleaning I used only terminal no GUI tool.